# HUE AND KEYCLOAK INTEGRATION 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, hue, idp

I have tried to do HUE with keycloak integration with OIDC configuration. Since i am using managed cluster, i have updated the hue_safety_value.ini with below configuration.
When i login with HUE url it is redirectly to keycloak login page. And once successful login it is redirect to HUE home page. But the problem is after sometime (around 15mins), am not able to access the hue UI. When i check the browser network page, I could see 403 error for all xhr request. In hue logs also, i could see session is expired and getting error.

My question is why HUE does not redirect the page to keycloak login page if the session is expired. I have to manually close the browser and open the hue url again.

```
[desktop]
  django_debug_mode=true
  [[auth]]
    backend=desktop.auth.backend.OIDCBackend
  [[oidc]]
    oidc_rp_client_id=test-client
    oidc_op_authorization_endpoint=https://xxxxxxxx/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    oidc_op_token_endpoint=https://xxxxxxxx/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token
    oidc_op_user_endpoint=https://xxxxxxxx/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
    oidc_rp_sign_algo=RS256
    oidc_op_jwks_endpoint=https://xxxxxxxx/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs
    oidc_verify_ssl=False
    login_redirect_url=https://huexxxxxxxx:8888/oidc/callback/
    logout_redirect_url=https://xxxxxxxx/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/logout
    login_redirect_url_failure=https://xxxxxxxx:8888/hue/oidc_failed/
```

Expecation: When the session expires, the page should redirect to keycloak login page or atleast if the page is refreshed then it should redirect to keycloak login page instead of hanging the same page